# Angular (service provider)

Tags: angular

I'm developing a hybrid app with ionic, angular, cordova and I created a service with the name `piecesservice`:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class PiecesService {
 private donnes: any;


constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
  }

 getCote(nomCote, nomRobot) {
this.http.get('./assets/etat_pieces.json').subscribe(
  data => {
    this.donnes = data;
    console.log(this.donnes);
    for (var i = 0; i < this.donnes.cote.length; i++) {
      if (this.donnes.cote[i].nom = nomCote) {
        for (var j = 0; j < this.donnes.cote[i].robots.length; j++)
          if (this.donnes.cote[i].robots[j].nom = nomRobot) {
            console.log(this.donnes.cote[i].robots[j].pieces);
            return this.donnes.cote[i].robots[j].pieces;
          }
      }
    }
    return this.donnes;
  });
 }
}
```

and a page `pieces.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {PiecesService} from "../services/pieces-service";
import { NavController, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
//import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
@Component({
 selector: 'page-pieces',
 templateUrl: 'pieces.html'
  })
 export class PiecesPage {
 info:any;

 constructor(public nav: NavController, public piecesService: PiecesService) {

  this.info = piecesService.getCote("Gauche", "Robot 2 DC 0912");
  console.log(this.info);

    }

  }
```

The problem is I can't read the data in the `pieces.ts` from the service it is mentioned as undefined in the console.log(this.info);

What can I do to get at the information?

Answer (score 2):

1) First create function in service file like,

```
public getAll(actionUrl: string): Observable<any[]> {
  return this.http.get<any[]>(API_URL + actionUrl);
}
```

Where (API_URL = base url)

Call this function from the component file like,

```
this.piecesService.getAll('./assets/etat_pieces.json')
  .subscribe((response: any) => {
    console.log(response.data);
  });
```

Now you can get the result.

Answer (score 1):

Replace subscribe in PiecesService with map and then in pieces.ts

```
 piecesService.getCote("Gauche", "Robot 2 DC 0912").subscribe(value => this.info = value);
```

Comment: I don't think you can call `subscribe` twice, can you?

Comment: havent seen this subscribe.it should be replaced with a map operator.

Comment: Well there is in the service but that observable is never returned. I was saying that I don't think `observable.subscribe(...).subscribe(...)` would work if that observable was returned as is and is in the component.

Comment: think you, but 
what should be the type of the  variable "info" ?? because I have this error " TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'."

Comment: try to add any in the function declaration getCote(nomCote, nomRobot): any

Comment: You also need to return the observable in your `getCote` method. See the code I added to my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Your function `getCote` doesn't return anything. Normally you don't call subscribe until you are where you want to use your data and should return the observable in the `getCote` function instead and then subscribe to it in your component. Or use the async pipe.

You could use the `map` function on the observable to transform the data before another part of your code subscribes to it.

Your code could look like this:

**pieces.service.ts**:

```
getCote(nomCote, nomRobot) {
  return this.http.get('./assets/etat_pieces.json').map(
    data => {
      this.donnes = data;
      console.log(this.donnes);
      for (var i = 0; i < this.donnes.cote.length; i++) {
        if (this.donnes.cote[i].nom = nomCote) {
          for (var j = 0; j < this.donnes.cote[i].robots.length; j++)
            if (this.donnes.cote[i].robots[j].nom = nomRobot) {
              console.log(this.donnes.cote[i].robots[j].pieces);
             return this.donnes.cote[i].robots[j].pieces;
            }
        }
      }
      return this.donnes;
  });
}
```

**pieces.component.ts**:

```
piecesService.getCote("Gauche", "Robot 2 DC 0912")
  .subscribe(info => console.log(this.info));
```

You could probably clean up the code inside the map function I added by using map/filter/reduce (more info [here](https://hackernoon.com/understanding-map-filter-and-reduce-in-javascript-5df1c7eee464)). Or at least by using foreach loops. I'm not sure why you store the data on `this.donnes` but maybe you are trying to cache it or something...

Comment: Why the downvote? I'm not in the Angular world as much anymore so if I've got something incorrect, please let me know. The top answer isn't very specific to the original code snippet asked about. The original code has several things incorrect (no return value, no async handling in component, adding map operator would allow service to be subscribed to in components) which I don't think are fully captured in the other answers. I haven't actually run this code so it could have a bug.

Answer (score -1):

Try using **async/await** Or just return the http observable and subscribe it in the UsedComponent(Page Pieces.ts)

Comment: `async/await` doesn't work with Observables right? Yes converting it to a promise and then using `async/await` would be fine. But that's probably not the suggested way of doing it, especially for beginners to Angular. If you weren't using observables and instead used raw promises, I'd definitely suggest it.

Comment: You can await on the http call i guess. Correct me,  if i am wrong.

Comment: http://embed.plnkr.co/bx8eGvIFWhqdzCqpB7fb/ Check this. I guess the problem is similar.

Comment: That code calls `.toPromise()`. Which is fine if that's what you want to do and it does allow you to use `async/await`. But then you're avoiding using observables which I guess is up to the preferences of a developer/team.